# Mask URL in Nginx for Kibana

Tags: nginx, proxy, url-rewriting, kibana

I have setup the Kibana with Nginx. But need to do some tweak on this. I mean , Need to mask the request URI.

For example:

from :
http://example.com/#/dashboard/file/logstash.json

to:
http://example.com/test

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all your URLs have a # in them, you can do this:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "request", "#.*", "test" ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you need something more generic, you could create a custom version of the %{URI} pattern that named the fields, and then replace the request field with the assembled bits (URIPROTO, USER, URIHOST).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where I need to change the above settings ?.  Please give some steps or any link if you have. Thanks in advance

Comment: Oops, I made the assumption your logs were going into elasticsearch with logstash.  Logstash would allow you to make the transformation you're looking for.  Also, kibana4 will allow you to run scripts against the output, but I think that's less efficient than fixing it on the way in.  If you have some other way of getting the logs into elasticsearch, please describe it.

Comment: I'm posting the data directly into elasticsearch and Not using Logstash here. I can have data view on the Kibana dashboard. But the problem here is the url expose the exact file path and file name. Will it be possible to mask the request url as mentioned above ?. If you say yes, please share your thoughts.

Comment: You can do it as a scripted field in kibana4.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using Kibana3. Can I do the same on this version ?. If yes, Please  share some reference link which may help me more to setup.